# How could I efficiently make a number's absolute value closer to zero?

Tags: java, absolute-value

I know one possible way of achieving this:

```
int a = 7;
int b = -10;

public int makeSmaller(int num) {
  int result = Math.abs(num) - 1;
  if(num > 0) return result;
  else return -result;
}

makeSmaller(a); //returns 6
makeSmaller(b); //returns -9
```

Are there any more concise way of doing this could use to make this a little cleaner?

**EDIT**

I want the method to return a result closer to zero by exactly 1, so dividing by 2 or any other number won't work. Neither will multiplying by 0.

Comment: You could also multiply it *by* zero. That will make the absolute value closer to zero.

Comment: AJ Weeks, you should meditate on @Mysticial's comment above and think about the importance of figuring out just what you are trying to accomplish before writing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Math.abs` doesn't gain you anything, since you are testing the sign anyway.

Thus, a more concise formulation:

```
public int makeSmaller(int num) {
  return num > 0? num-1 : num+1;
}
```

Since you say you want to make it closer to zero, you should also check the zero case:

```
public int towardZero(int num) {
  if (num == 0) return 0;
  else return num > 0? num-1 : num+1;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using signum:

```
public static int makeSmaller(int val) {
    return val-Integer.signum(val);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public int makeSmaller(int num) {
  int result = Math.abs(num) - 1;
  if(num > 0) return result;
  else return -result;
}
```

Why not just this?

```
public int makeSmaller(int num) {
    return num - (num/Math.abs(num));
}
```

The parenthetical part will always have the same sign as the number, and will always be 1 (plus or minus).

So, given 7...

7 - (7/|7|) = 7 - 1 = 6

Given -10...

-10 - (-10/|-10|) = - 10 - (-10/10) = -10 - (-1) = -10 + 1 = -9

Comment: You might have a problem when `num` is `0`...

Answer (score 0):

Not very readable, but working:

```
    int q = -10;

    final int s[] = new int[]{-1, 1};
    q += s[(q>>>31)];

    System.out.println(q); // print -9

    int q = 10;

    final int s[] = new int[]{-1, 1};
    q += s[(q>>>31)];

    System.out.println(q); // print 9
```

So you can rewrite your function as:

```
final static int[] signsInc = new int[]{-1, 1};
public static int makeSmaller(final int num) {
    return (num != 0) ? (num + signsInc[(num>>>31)]) : 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not move the `signsInc` declaration into the method definition?

Comment: @dfeuer there is no sense to create array each time function is called, it is static data and should be outside the method

Comment: Methods can have static variables too. Whether static variables are ever clean is another question, but it makes no difference whether they're declared in a method or in its enclosing class—they're only initialized once in any case.

Comment: @dfeuer are you sure that static variables can be declared inside method in java?

Comment: you're right. I got confused.